# Dash import fails on Python

Tags: python, installation, pip, plotly-dash

I have Python 3.12.0 installed and running properly. I am able to import and use Pandas and NumPy. I have pip installed Dash. Everytime I try to `import dash`, I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'

I have uninstalled and re-installed Python and tried several ideas.  How can I get my system to recognize Dash and allow me to import and use it? I researched virtual environments. I do not think I need a virtual environment. I am trying to run this through **Spyder**. Thank you in advance.

Comment: _" I have pip installed Dash"_ to which interpreter? Are you sure that the pip executable you used was the one for the 3.12.0 interpreter, and not a different interpreter installed on your system? To make sure you're using the 3.12 interpreter's pip, try using `python3.12 -m pip` instead.